# Android - Facebook SDK 3 - How to login programatically from non-activity class

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to login and send Facebook requests from a non-Activity class?
All the samples I found override the method `onActivityResult` of the Activity class to get the result a Facebook login activity.

I want to create the same code as the SDK sample `GraphApiSampleActivity`, but not called from an Activity.

As I mentioned, my problem is I cannot override `onActivityResult` to get login result. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK uses intents to start a new activity to do the authorization workflow, and passes back the access token (and other associated information) through the onActivityResult method. Since it uses intents with a result, it must initiate the authorization with either an activity or a fragment.

Why can't you use an Activity (or Fragment)? Are you dependent on some other SDK?

Comment: I'm creating an API that will be used by other applications. The calls to fb SKD will be performed from my library. In my library i have custom classes, i dont use Activities. When my library is initialized i keep a reference to the application context & the active activity.

Comment: You can either leave the Facebook login to your users, and have them pass in a Session that's already open, or you can have them implement onActivityResult in one of their activities (that starts the login process), and pass the result to your SDK. An example of this is how Parse includes the Facebook SDK - https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers